# How do I add "Reply To" to this in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, [to_email])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

How do I add the "reply to" header?

Comment: This is discussed in the documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects No offense, but seems like many of your Django questions are covered in the documentation. The documentation is pretty well written and, many times, offer you some great and useful insight on many topics.

Answer (score 25):

You'll want to add a `Reply-To` header to the `EmailMessage`.

```
headers = {'Reply-To': reply_email}
msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, [to_email], headers=headers)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 16):

As of Django 1.8 there is an argument that can be passed into the constructor of `EmailMessage` named [`reply_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage) that will handle the headers logic for you.